# BlackBerry - Facebook connect from application

Tags: facebook, blackberry, java-me, authentication

i m developing a blackberry app which requires facebook login. can i login to facebook via my app without stopping the app in the middle. means can i login to facebook in parallel with my application, without interrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make your program multithreaded, and handle the connection to facebook in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends whether the User of your application has already grants your application the access to his/her profile. If it is true, you would then have the session key (valid and non-expiring) for the User and no login is required. Furthermore, some methods do not require session at all (cf. Facebook API documentation).

Comment: what if the user has not granted the request..?? how to proceed further in that case..

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much your app can do as Desktop application (Facebook Connect) requires session key. (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Category:Sessionless_API)